# local variable cannot be assigned as final

Tags: java

I have a variable that asks me to make it final, but when making it final I get an error that says the following: "The final local variable "enter" cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an endclosing type"

How could you declare such a variable?

```
void yyyyyy(ActionEvent event){

final Scanner enter = null;

try{
.
.
.
enter = new Scaner(xxxxx);

}catch(){
....
}finally{
  if(enter != null){
}
}
```

Comment: Remove the initialization: `final Scanner enter = null` -> `final Scanner enter;`

Comment: I think we need to see where `enter` is going to be used.

Comment: the problem is that null I use it in the finally, hence I can't get out the null statement

Comment: Then you need to not declare it as `final`.  Or (definitely) initialize it before the `try`.  The point is that a `final` variable can only be assigned once.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "that asks me to make it final"?

Comment: It is not possible to make the variable `final` in this particular situation. You have to assign a value to it beforehand in order to not have an uninitialized local variable in your `finally` block but you also have to assign the true value inside the `try` block. So this situation can not be solved.

Comment: In case you want to create a scanner tied to `System.in`, **do not close it**. Also, note that there is **try-with-resources** which greatly simplifies this `try-catch-finally` to just `try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(...)) { ... }` and thats it. Then you can also make it `final`. Java will auto-close it for you, no need for `catch` or `finally`.

Answer (score 3):

Right now you declare the variable and initialize it in the same time. Since it's final, you can not assign values to it more, than once.

If you remove assignment from initialization, you still can not make this variable final, because you check it for null in finally block. For that logic to work, variable should be assigned null explicitly somewhere. And that's impossible, because try block could throw an exception in the first line.

Whatever asks you to make the variable final - ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work like this. As some other answers are explaining, you can't assign value for final variable twice.

You can make it work like this

```
void yyyyyy(final ActionEvent event) {
    Scanner enter = null;
    try {
        enter = new Scanner("/");
    } catch (final Exception exception) {

    } finally {
        enter.close();
    }
}
```